# Doctrine 2: inserting data into an entity with associations

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

Solved by adding a conditional when adding a new entity to the database, it checks if the entity is not null... apparently there was null entities trying to get saved. Now the controller code looks like this:

```
...
$ciudades_id = explode(';', $this->getRequest()->getParam('ciudades_id'));
           foreach($ciudades_id as $ciudad_id){
               $ciudad = $this->_em->find("Application_Model_Ciudades", intval($ciudad_id));
               if($ciudad!= null){
                $carrera->getCiudad()->add($ciudad);                  
               }
           }


           $instituciones_id = explode(';', $this->getRequest()->getParam('instituciones_id'));
           foreach($instituciones_id as $institucion_id){
               $institucion = $this->_em->find("Application_Model_Instituciones", intval($institucion_id));
               if($institucion != null){
                  $carrera->getInstituciones()->add($institucion); 
               }
           }
...
```

**Thanks to the guys that helped at #doctrine IRC channel :)**

---

This is my problem... I got an entity called "Carreras" (carreers) that has some associations, and the new carreers are added to the database with a web form. A carreer for me is a test, which has questions and other atttributes, and the user can select the cities and institutions that apply for that test.

So i'm getting this error when i try to save new data on the entity:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: A new entity was found through the relationship
'Application_Model_Carreras#ciudad' that was not configured 
to cascade persist operations for entity: Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork@. 
Explicitly persist    the new entity or configure cascading persist 
operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity 
causes the problem implement 'Application_Model_Ciudades#__toString()' 
to get a clue.
```

This is the model for "Carreras"

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="carreras")
 */
class Application_Model_Carreras
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_PruebasCarrera")
     * @JoinTable(name="Carreras_PruebasCarrera",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="carreras_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pruebascarrera_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $pruebas;


    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $valor;

    /** @Column(type="date") */
    private $fechainicio;

    /** @Column(type="date") */
    private $fechafin;

    /**
     * This association causes error
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_Ciudades")
     * @JoinTable(name="carrera_ciudades",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="carrera_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ciudad_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $ciudad;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_Instituciones")
     * @JoinTable(name="carrera_instituciones",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="carrera_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="institucion_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $instituciones;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pruebas = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->ciudad = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->instituciones = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setNombre($nombre){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    public function setValor($valor){
        $this->valor = $valor;
    }

    public function setFechainicio($fechainicio){
        $this->fechainicio = $fechainicio;
    }

    public function setFechafin($fechafin){
        $this->fechafin = $fechafin;
    }

    public function getCiudad(){
        return $this->ciudad;
    }

    public function getPruebas(){
        return $this->pruebas;
    }

    public function getInstituciones(){
        return $this->instituciones;
    }
}
```

Now the action at controller:

```
 /*
     * This is an action for adding a new career
     */
    public function agregarAction()
    {
       $formtest = new Admin_Form_AgregarCarrera();
       $this->view->formtest = $formtest;
       if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->view->formtest->isValid($this->_getAllParams()))
       {
           /*
            * If the form is okay creating new Carreer model object
            * This model has some attributes and three associations (for now) 
            * you can see them later in detail
            */
           $carrera = new Application_Model_Carreras();
           $carrera->setNombre($this->getRequest()->getParam("nombre"));
           $carrera->setValor($this->getRequest()->getParam("valor"));
           $carrera->setFechainicio(new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->getParam("fechainicio")));
           $carrera->setFechafin(new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->getParam("fechafin")));
           /*
            * This is the first association. It's working fine (for now)
            */
           $pruebas = $this->getRequest()->getParam("pruebas");
           foreach($pruebas as $prueba){
              if($prueba != '0'){
                  $tmp = $this->_em->find("Application_Model_PruebasCarrera", $prueba);
                  $carrera->getPruebas()->add($tmp);
              }
           }
           /*
            * This is the second associations, i'm getting the error with this one
            */
           $ciudades_id = explode(';', $this->getRequest()->getParam('ciudades_id'));
           foreach($ciudades_id as $ciudad_id){
               $ciudad = $this->_em->find("Application_Model_Ciudades", intval($ciudad_id));
               $carrera->getCiudad()->add($ciudad);
           }
           /*
            * This is the third one. Nothing to say about this.
            */
           $instituciones_id = explode(';', $this->getRequest()->getParam('instituciones_id'));
           foreach($instituciones_id as $institucion_id){
               $institucion = $this->_em->find("Application_Model_Instituciones", intval($institucion_id));
               $carrera->getInstituciones()->add($institucion);
           }

           $this->_em->persist($carrera);
           $this->_em->flush();
           //$this->redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit('index','Carrera','admin');     
        }
    }
```

Well i don't know what else to show... please comment if you can help me :)

--edit

I added cascade={"persist"} in the associations of the model "Carreras" and the error changed:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Class Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork is not a 
valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Now this is "Ciudades" model, it stores the cities available for the test and is associated with the institutions that exist on every city.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ciudades")
 */
class Application_Model_Ciudades {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $ciudad;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $departamento;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $pais;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_Instituciones")
     * @JoinTable(name="Ciudades_Instituciones",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ciudades_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="instituciones_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $instituciones;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->instituciones = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getCiudad(){
        return $this->ciudad;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getInstituciones(){
        return $this->instituciones;
    }

}
```

Now this is "Instituciones" Model, it stores the institutions available for the tests.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="instituciones")
 */
class Application_Model_Instituciones {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $nombre;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }

}
```

Now this is "PruebasCarrera" Model, for me this model entity stores the questions of the tests, and every question can have a partner who supports the question:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="pruebas_carrera")
 */
class Application_Model_PruebasCarrera extends Application_Model_PruebasBase{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_Patrocinadores")
     * @JoinTable(name="pruebascarrera_patrocinadores",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pruebas_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique="true")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="patrocinadores_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
     *      )
     */
    protected $patrocinadores;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $respuesta; 

    public function __construct() {
        $this->patrocinadores = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setRespuesta($respuesta){
        $this->respuesta = $respuesta;
    }

    public function getPatrocinadores(){
        return $this->patrocinadores;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRespuesta(){
        return $this->respuesta;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show code of related entities: 
Application_Model_Ciudades
Application_Model_PruebasCarrera
Application_Model_Instituciones

At this moment look https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

At this moment i think you should add cascade={"persist"} to the Application_Model_Ciudades entity.